# llvm-ld still exist for clang 3.4 ?

Tags: c++, c, linker, llvm, ld

Last time I checked on clang it was at the version 3.1/3.2, now I'm under Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit and I installed clang and llvm ( plus the tools ) from the official apt repository but there is no trace of `llvm-ld-3.4`, `llvm-ld-3.0` and `llvm-ld-3.1` are the only 2 versions of this tool that are available on my machine, my question is: whit what I'm supposed to replace llvm-ld and generate a library or a machine executable ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`llvm-ld` no longer exists. From [LLVM 3.2 release notes](http://llvm.org/releases/3.2/docs/ReleaseNotes.html):

> llvm-ld and llvm-stub have been removed, llvm-ld functionality can be partially replaced by llvm-link | opt | {llc | as, llc -filetype=obj} | ld, or fully replaced by Clang.

Or, in a nicer format:

1. Link all your .bc / .ll files with `llvm-link`, to get one bitcode file
2. Run `opt` to optimize the bitcode file
3. Generate an object file, through one of

   - `llc` to get asm file, then system assembler (`as`) to get an object file
   - `llc -filetype=obj` to get an object file (this just calls the system assembler on its own)
4. System linker (`ld`) to link your object files with all other required object files

As for *why* it was removed, check out [this LLVM-dev discussion](http://llvm.1065342.n5.nabble.com/llvm-ld-td59389.html).

Also, you might be interested in this related question: [How to link object to libraries with LLVM >= 3.1 ? ( no GNU ld )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528474/how-to-link-object-to-libraries-with-llvm-3-1-no-gnu-ld)

Comment: so basically the only option is the GNU `ld` ? I'm curious about why they have done this and what happens in a MAC OS X environment, they use `ld` under MAC too ? My curiosity is also about the `-O4` optimization level, what to do in this case ?

Comment: @user2485710 updated my answer. The links I've provided also mention getting LTO to work.